# How can I switch my Rails App timezone to PST?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I've tried

```
config.time.in_time_zone("Pacific Time (US & Canada)")
```

as well as

```
config.time_zone("PST")
```

and both caused errors and caused the heroku app to crash. What is the proper way to switch my app to PST time?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place the following in your `config/application.rb` and restart rails server:

```
config.time_zone = 'Pacific Time (US & Canada)'
```

Here is the description from [`Rails Guides Configuring Rails Application`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html):

> config.time_zone sets the default time zone for the application and
>   enables time zone awareness for Active Record.

Then the usage for `in_time_zone`:

```
> Date.today
=> Thu, 13 Mar 2014

> Time.zone
=> (GMT-08:00) Pacific Time (US & Canada)

> Date.today.to_time.in_time_zone
=> Wed, 12 Mar 2014 21:00:00 PDT -07:00
```

To output a time in different time zone:

```
> Date.today.to_time.in_time_zone('Eastern Time (US & Canada)')
=> Wed, 13 Mar 2014 00:00:00 EDT -04:00
```